# Ember oauth user authentication with google, then automatic registration on rest api, dilema

Tags: api, rest, authentication, ember.js, oauth

I will have rest api written in Python and Flask. For now only client which will interact with that API is website written in EmberJS. I will use basic auth with tokens for authentication. But I also want to enable user to authenticate with other services (google, facebook...) with oauth (ember-oauth2).

[Ember-oauth2](https://github.com/amkirwan/ember-oauth2) is purely client side authentication and my ember website will end up with the api token from the authentication service when the user signs in with it. Now, I would like to propagate that info to the backend rest api end get the token (and auto-register user if it is his first login) with which the ember app will continue to interact with the api, just like when the user logins via basic auth.

I think of sending the token that is given by the authentication service (for example Google) along with the users email to the rest api and from the rest api check the token with for example https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token= and if the email from that request matches with the email sent to the api I will create the token for the ember app.

So :

1. User clicks "login with Google" on the ember website.
2. After oauth flow user is authenticated and ember app have googles token
3. Ember app POSTs token and email to /api/session
4. Rest api checks the token and that emails match with the https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token= call.
5. Rest api registers the user if it is his first login.
6. Rest api creates the token (with TTL, saved in Redis) which is used for further communication and returns it to the ember app.

Is this approach safe and secure (I will use SSL) or is there a better way?

Comment: Instead of redirecting to the Ember app and having it POST the token, why not just have the oauth redirect return directly to the server?  It does what it needs, then redirects to the Ember app as an authenticated user.

Comment: In Ember-Oauth2 readme `{redirectUri: 'https://oauth2-login-demo.appspot.com/oauth/callback'}` This will happen in an iframe so your main app won't get reloaded.

Comment: @SteveH. Hm, my flask rest api is served by one server and ember website from the other. If oauth flow is initiated by the ember app and I provide the redirect url to be that of the flask api, I can`t redirect than back from flask to ember because they are decoupled and ember did not initiate oauth to the rest api so it can return the answer when it finishes, it initiated with the 3rd party website. Or maybe I just confused something?